# JBoss Developer Studio 11.0.0.GA perfomance problems on Windows 7

Tags: jboss, redhat, jboss-developer-studio

I'm working with Jboss Developer Studio on Windows 7 SP1 and i have a problems with perfomance.
For example, when i'm trying to open complex **camel-context.xml** file i should waiting for 3-5 mintues while studio is loading. Also, when i'm trying to **clean/rebuild** my project i should waiting for a long time too.

My hardware:

- i7-6700 CPU @ 3.4Ghz
- 16 Gb RAM

OS: Windows 7 SP1

So, i'd tried to switch off all automatic updates of studio, but it didn't help.

Is it OS problem or other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be your OS. Win7SP1 is more than 7 years old [1]. Can you upgrade to Windows 10?

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7#Service_Pack_1

It could also be related to firewalls or proxies, if there are background processes running which are blocked by the network and are re-attempting connections which keep failing.

Did you opt in to send AERI error reports back to eclipse.org? That could be another background process you could opt out of.

Or, it could be an existing problem, already reported here [2] or here [3].

[2] https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBDS-4488

[3] https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBDS-4680

If it's one of those problems, please attach more information to those issues -- console logs, screenshots, or any other details you can collect to help identify the problem. Please be sure to mention your OS and JDK details, and how you installed devstudio 11 -- was it the .jar installer? the devsuite installer for Windows? or a BYOE install from the update site or the Eclipse Marketplace?